# Pandas Correlation One Column to Many Columns Group by range of the column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, correlation

Assuming I have a data frame similar to the below (actual data frame has million observations), how would I get the correlation between signal column and list of return columns, then group by the `Signal_Up` column?

I tried the pandas `corrwith` function but it does not give me the correlation grouping for the `signal_up` column

```
df[['Net_return_at_t_plus1', 'Net_return_at_t_plus5',
           'Net_return_at_t_plus10']].corrwith(df['Signal_Up']))
```

I am trying to look for correlation between signal column and other net returns columns group by various values of signal_up column.

Data and desired result is given below.

Desired Result

[image: Desired Result]

Data

[image: Data Frame]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the correlations by individual category of Signal_Up column by using “groupby” function. However, I am not able to apply “corr” function to more than two columns.

So, I had to use “concat” function to combine all of them.

```
a = df.groupby('Signal_Up')[['signal','Net_return_at_t_plus1']].corr().unstack().iloc[:,1] 

b = df.groupby('Signal_Up')[['signal','Net_return_at_t_plus5']].corr().unstack().iloc[:,1] 

c = df.groupby('Signal_Up')[['signal','Net_return_at_t_plus10']].corr().unstack().iloc[:,1] 

dfCorr = pd.concat([a, b, c], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple dataframe below:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'v1': [1, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7],
                  'v2': [2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4],
                  'v3': [3, 3, 2, 9, 2, 5],
                  'v4': [4, 5, 1, 4, 2, 5]})
```

(1st interpretation) one way to get correlations of one variable with the other columns is:

```
correlations = df.corr().unstack().sort_values(ascending=False) # Build correlation matrix
correlations = pd.DataFrame(correlations).reset_index() # Convert to dataframe
correlations.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'correlation'] # Label it
correlations.query("col1 == 'v2' & col2 != 'v2'") # Filter by variable
# output of this code will give correlation of column v2 with all the other columns
```

(2nd interpretation) one way to get correlations of column v1 with column v3, v4 after grouping by column v2 is using this one line:

```
df.groupby('v2')[['v1', 'v3', 'v4']].corr().unstack()['v1']
```

In your case, v2 is 'Signal_Up', v1 is 'signal' and v3, v4 columns proxy 'Net_return_at_t_plusX' columns.

Comment: Thanks @Zolzaya Luvsandorj for the help here. I just edited my original question. I am looking for correlation between signal column and other net returns columns group them by various values of signal_up column. So, essentially Correlation between "signal" column and list of "Net return" columns but not the whole columns but according to different categories/ ranges (-4, -1, 3, 5, 6) of the column "Signal_Up".

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong @ClaudeTi, my thinking is that: if we group by Signal_Up, then there will be no variation in grouped data in Signal_Up column (there will be variation in other columns). What this probably means is that correlation is nan in the absence of variation, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks @zolzaya luvsandorj. I am able to get the correlations by individual category of Signalu_Up column by using “groupby” function. However, I am not able to appy “corr” function to more than two columns. So, I had to use “concat” function to combine all of them. 
a = df.groupby('Signal_Up')[['signal,'Net_return_at_t_plus1']].corr().unstack().iloc[:,1]
b = df.groupby('Signal_Up')[['signal','Net_return_at_t_plus5']].corr().unstack().iloc[:,1]
c = df.groupby('Signal_Up')[['signal','Net_return_at_t_plus10']].corr().unstack().iloc[:,1]
dfCorr = pd.concat([a, b, c], axis=1)

Comment: I have updated my answer to include suggestion for this question (i.e. not having to do it one by one and concat afterwards).